# Thingsboard - Split up telemetry data

Tags: split, thingsboard, telemetry

I have a device that gets this telemetry data:

{"eventType":"EVT_IM_ALIVE","serialNum":"000096c0e8d1","mac":"b827eb95bd84"}

[Picture of telemetry data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGYRW.png)

Is there a way to split this data up so i can use eventType, serialNum and mac by them self?

Comment: You can reformat data in Rule Chains. Just add [Transformation script](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/transformation-nodes/#script-transformation-node) before saving to database

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ThingsBoard PE you can use Integrations & Data Converter for splitting the data before saving:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/integrations/#uplink-data-converter

Answer (score 0):

If you save this telemetry in rule chain, it will automatically split into 3 telemetries for you, the body must be:

```
{
  "eventType": "EVT_IM_ALIVE",
  "serialNum": "000096c0e8d1",
  "mac": "b827eb95bd84"
}
```

not:

```
{
  data:{
    "eventType": "EVT_IM_ALIVE",
    "serialNum": "000096c0e8d1",
    "mac": "b827eb95bd84"
  }
}
```